# How can I create a stored procedure of inheritance tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have three tables

```
create table CustomerTypes(
CustomerTypeID int primary key identity(1,1),
CustomerType varchar(11)
);

insert into CustomerTypes(CustomerTypeID,CustomerType)
select 1, 'Regular' union all
select 2, 'Business'

create table Customers(
ContactID int primary key identity(1,1),
CustomerTypeID int references CustomerTypes(CustomerTypeID),
FirstName varchar(25)not null,
LastName varchar(25)not null,
DOB date not null,
Telephone varchar(18),
Notes varchar(250),
AddDate date not null
constraint cust_AltPK unique (ContactID,CustomerTypeID)
);

create table Regular_Customer(
ContactID int primary key identity(1,1),
CustomerTypeID as 1 persisted, --regular
Specification varchar(45),
Date_Joined date,
foreign key (ContactID,CustomerTypeID) references Customers(ContactID,CustomerTypeID)
);

create table Business_Customer(
ContactID int primary key identity(1,1),
CustomerTypeID as 2 persisted, --Business
Business_Name varchar(30)not null,
Business_Type varchar(30),
foreign key (ContactID,CustomerTypeID) references Customers(ContactID,CustomerTypeID)
);
```

I want to create a stored procedure called CustRegistration to insert data into the various customer tables, by combining customerType table and Customer table.

Comment: thank's RDFozz. for the CustRegistration stored procedure, i need to combine two tables: customerType to select one type of the customer (1:Regular or 2:Business) and insert it to the CustomerTypeID of customer table referencing CustomerType. Any idea on how to do it.

Comment: i am posting what i did but i am not getting the result i am expecting

Comment: Sorry, it's really not clear what the `CustRegistration` procedure should do. Combine what two tables? Insert what to the `CustomerTypeID` (it's got to be 1 or 2). From the description, it sounds like you want to insert a row into `Customer` for every row in one of the other two `*_Customer` tables, but only inserting the `CustomerTypeId` (leaving everything else blank) - which makes no sense whatsoever. I'm sorry I'm having difficulty understanding.

Comment: custRegistation procedure  will create a registration form for normal customer by selecting the type from custmerType table. My question is how to create a stored proc to insert data between tables (CustomerType,Customer and RegularCustomer)

Comment: Note that you don't create forms in SQL, so the SQL stored proc won't create a registration form.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to mimic inheritance in MS SQL Server, you'd technically create three procedures:

- `RegularCustRegistration`: insert a regular customer
- `BusinessCustRegistration`: insert a business customer
- `CustRegistration`: insert common data to `Customer`

NOTE: Since the `ContactID` in `Regular_Customer` and `Business_Customer` must match the one in `Customer`, you need to remove the `IDENTITY` attribute on those two tables. All `ContactID` values must be generated from `Customer`.

The code for `CustRegistration` and `RegularCustRegistration` would look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CustRegistration
      ( @ContactID int OUTPUT
       ,@CustomerTypeId int
       ,@FirstName varchar(25)
       ,@LastName varchar(25)
       ,@DOB date
       ,@Telephone varchar(18)
       ,@Notes varchar(250)
       ,@AddDate date
      )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @CustOut TABLE (ContactID int);

    INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerTypeId, FirstName, LastName, DOB, Telephone, Notes, AddDate)
    OUTPUT INSERTED.ContactID INTO @CustOut
    VALUES (@CustomerTypeId, @FirstName, @LastName, @DOB, @Telephone, @Notes, @AddDate);

    SELECT TOP (1) @ContactID = ContactID
      FROM @CustOut;
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE RegularCustRegistration
      ( @FirstName varchar(25)
       ,@LastName varchar(25)
       ,@DOB date
       ,@Telephone varchar(18) = NULL
       ,@Notes varchar(250) = NULL
       ,@AddDate date
       ,@Specification varchar(45) = NULL
       ,@Date_Joined date = NULL
      )
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ContactID int;
    DECLARE @CustomerTypeID int = 1; -- regular

    EXECUTE CustRegistration
            @ContactID OUTPUT
           ,@CustomerTypeID
           ,@FirstName
           ,@LastName
           ,@DOB
           ,@Telephone
           ,@Notes
           ,@AddDate
    ;

    INSERT INTO Regular_Customer (ContactID, Specification, Date_Joined)
    VALUES (@ContactID, @Specification, @Date_Joined);
END;
```

See this [dbfiddle.uk link](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7c8aa26c1089af05b9061ebd2192f0fd) to see this work. It also has corrected versions of your table creation statements (`IDENTITY` removed from `Regular_Customer` and `Business_Customer`; `PRIMARY KEY` has to come after `IDENTITY(1,1)`; need to use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT <table> ON` to insert explicit values to an `IDENTITY` column).

Since we need the identity value from the `Customers` table to create our row in `Regular_Customer`, we use the `OUTPUT` clause of the `INSERT` statement to capture the ID created by the `INSERT`, and mark the `@ContactID` parameter of the `CustRegistration` procedure as an `OUTPUT` parameter, so the value put in that parameter is passed back to the specified variable in the calling procedure.

You should be able to create `BusinessCustRegistration` based on this.